# Reason for computer not booting when power button pressed

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

I have a following problem starting my desktop computer and I'm trying to figure out the root cause. Most of the time it will just start normally when I press the power button. On some occasions however, when I switch the computer off via shutdown option in Windows, I'm unable to start it again using the power button. It just does nothing and will only start once I turn off power supply to the PSU and leave it that way for a couple minutes. Sometimes it also seems like it matters what devices are plugged into the front USB ports, though I don't understand how that could influence power up sequence.

I'm wondering if this might be caused by the mobo, the PSU or maybe some wiring problem with the power button. Please, advise.

Comment: We have this issue with a good number of our machines and our supplier contract usually results in replacing both the PSU and motherboard. It seems to be Intel boards with i5 processors as we have a variety of i3 to i7's.

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what boards/PSUs you are using? Mine is enermax PSU with Gigabyte mobo and an i5.

Comment: MB: Intel DQ67SW & PSU: FSP Group Inc. P/N: 9PA300CU01. I'm very surprised a Gigabyte board is giving you grief... well, I suppose, it can happen at any time on any hardware!

Comment: I'll probably just start with the PSU, as I've had this one for a long time and been meaning to replace it for one with longer wiring anyway. Will see about the motherboard later, altough I must say I've had problems with keyboard in certain USB ports from the begining (same symptom, fans would not even start to spin).